# Word order in 能源保障供应

Tags: word-order

"能源保障供应" ([Source](https://www.thepaper.cn/newsDetail_forward_14884618)) seems to mean "to guarantee the supply of energy". But I would have guessed the word order to be "保障能源供应", with the verb in front. Why is this not the case?

Comment: Have you got the whole sentence, or paragraph??

Comment: @Pedroski See the source I linked to in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Technologically both are correct. But 能源保障供应 puts a bit emphasis on the action 保障, which is the main content of 工作.

Another example 洪水治理工作(instead of 治理洪水工作), the emphasis is put on 治理. That means the work is to find ways to 治理洪水.

Answer (score 1):

"习近平总书记就能源供应保障、能源安全、能源产供储销体系建设等相关工作作出重要批示指示。"

习近平总书记 issued important instructions on the related works of guaranteed energy supply (in the season ahead), the safety of energy source, construction of the energy production, storage and sale's system.

Your sentence is equally applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Although in English, the so-called "Past Tense" is considered to be a verb form, we have no qualms about using it as an adjective, both before and after nouns: "A watched kettle never boils."

1. is talking about 'the supply'
2. is talking about 'a guarantee'

> 1. 能源保障供应
>    energy guarantee supply
>    a guaranteed supply of energy

> 2. 能源供应保障
>    energy provision guarantee
>    an energy provision assurance

，介绍今冬明春能源保障供应有关情况并答记者问。
, introduce the situation vis-à-vis the guaranteed supply of energy this winter and next spring and to answer journalists' questions

Comment: I take it then that my initial guess 保障能源供应 would be read as something being done (to guarantee) rather than as a thing (a guarantee)?

Comment: Interpreting is an art, not a science. Whoever interprets will put their own spin on things. I found: 保障能源供应 as "energy supply security" I would say, these 3 words are nouns,

Answer (score 0):

I think the editor wrote something wrong:

> 介绍今冬明春能源保障供应有关情况并答记者问

should be

> 介绍今冬明春能源保障**和**供应**的**有关情况并答记者问 —— introducing the situation about the guaranteed use of energy and energy supplication, and answering journalists' questions

能源供应保障 —— guaranty of energy supplication

(能源保障供应 make no sense to me)

保障能源供应 —— guarantee the supplication of energy.